# check for most used ids in csv file (Python)

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that has a list of ids. I want to do 2 things:
1. eliminate duplicates.
2. I also want to ensure that the ids that feature more show up on top. Ex: if id 100 shows up 20 times and id 95 shows up 12 times, I want id 100 to be on top.

what would be a good way to do this in python? - esp #2. I have an idea about how to do #1.

Comment: Look at `Counter` in `collections`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the sample csv file ? Is each ID on a new line ? Can you read the file and store each of these IDs into a list ?

Once you read each of these ids into a python list and then use the `Counter` from `collections` to count the most_common() items. This solves the problem of duplicates too as it only gives you one entry for each ID and it's corresponding count

```
from collections import Counter
data = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,0,0,0,0]
Counter(data).most_common()
```

results in

```
>>> data = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,0,0,0,0]
>>> Counter(data).most_common()
[(6, 9), (3, 5), (0, 4), (4, 4), (2, 3), (7, 3), (1, 2), (5, 2), (8, 2), (9, 1)]
```